# adding global stylesheet gatsby

Tags: css, gatsby

I created a gastby site using [their doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-1/)

and would like to add some global style (without a layout component) as per [this doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/#adding-global-styles-without-a-layout-component).

I'd like to add this to [my current repository](https://github.com/robdll/portfolio-gatsby) which is essentially the starter kit.

I've created the global.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

and the gatsby-browser.js files

```
import "./src/styles/global.css"
```

but no changes are reflected.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cloned your repo and I see all the styles applied. In fact, I've added a `background-color: red` to the `body` tag and I'm still seeing it:

[image: Working CSS styles]

Run `gatsby clean` to ensure that you are not seeing any cached version.

Comment: either `gatsby clean`  or restarting the environment solved it. dumb me, thanks a lot